# If you want to implement custom field-wise search functionality in the WordPress admin area

Tags: php, functions

```
function extend_admin_search( $query ) {

    // Extend search for document post type
    $post_type = 'document';
    // Custom fields to search for
    $custom_fields = array(
        "_file_name",
        "_file_name",
    );

    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( $query->query['post_type'] != $post_type )
        return;

    $search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];

    // Set to empty, otherwise it won't find anything
    $query->query_vars['s'] = '';

    if ( $search_term != '' ) {
        $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

        foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
            array_push( $meta_query, array(
                'key' => $custom_field,
                'value' => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
        }

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    };
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extend_admin_search' );
```

Comment: So... what's the question? There's no question here. Is the code you provided not working? Please provide more details before an answer can be given.

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress development. This is not a code review site and none of us are much good at mind reading (I can't read minds at all). To get quality answers you should have an actual question. For example, what your objective is, what you have tried, the problem or error you ran into... That sort of thing. Well-written questions tend to get great answers so please edit your question and expand a bit with some of the points I suggested.